# How to convert SQL select statement with particular fields and where clause to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-analysis, pandasql

I am trying to convert fallowing SQL statement into pandas dataframe in python

```
SELECT sum(money) from df where sex='female'
```

I am unable to get this in pandas

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

df.loc[df.sex=='female','money'].sum()